# How does 也 work in 宁愿冻死也不穿?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs

In the following sentence:

> 很多人因为害怕穿秋裤显胖，宁愿冻死**也**不穿。

What does 也 mean in the sentence? The entire sentence should mean something like the following:

> Because of the fear that wearing one more pants behind the trousers make you look fat, so many people rather want to...

I don't understand the last part of the sentence, especially on the 也 part.

According no Pleco, 也 has the following entry (as an adverb):

> [for emphasis, often before a negative expression]
>
> - 她一天假也没请过。

But then how does it connect 冻死 and 不穿 and what does the sentence mean?

Also, is my understanding that 也 here works as an emphasis correct?

Comment: I think it's a bit like "still"

Comment: 宁愿A也不B structure means **prefer A to B** or **would rather A than B**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this sentence `也` should not be understood individually.In Chinese `宁愿...也...` is a coordinating conjunction. It means a choose relationship. You choose the option behind `宁愿` and you give up the option behind `也`.
I think it seems like `rather...than...` in English.`宁愿冻死也不穿` may be translated to `rather be dead than be wearing the long underwear`.
More examples about `宁愿...也...`could be see in [here](http://fanyi.baidu.com/#zh/en/%E5%AE%81%E6%84%BF%20%E4%B9%9F);
And More examples about coordinating conjunction in Chinese could be see in [here](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%B9%B6%E5%88%97%E8%BF%9E%E8%AF%8D/6573724?fr=aladdin)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the answer. It seems that often the phrase after 也 comes with 不 on 不愿.

Comment: @Blaszard Thanks for being accepted and I'm glad to know that you seek out the regularity.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the definition 3 in [this dictionary:](http://www.zdic.net/z/15/js/4E5F.htm)

> 3. 在复句中表转折意：虽然你不说，我～能猜个八九不离十。

也 is used as the adverbial of concession, like the English word **although**. 也 follows the result or conclusion.

Comment: actually, I think it is just 'and'

Answer (score 1):

If it makes it easier to remember, you can relate this usage to the more common gloss of 'also': "[in situations where] people are freezing to death, they'd also prefer not to wear [them].

Or in more natural English: "... won't wear them even if they're freezing to death."

Answer (score 0):

It could be better understood as "still" here in our context.

Even if I get frozen, I "still" would not wear it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: in the cold light of morning:

I agree with Jian: 宁愿 A 也不愿B： would rather A than B

Literally: 宁愿A也不愿B would want A and not  want B

很多人
A lot of people
因为害怕穿秋裤显胖，
because they are afraid of appearing fat if they wear long-johns,
宁愿冻死也不穿。
would rather freeze to death than wear them.

(I prefer fat-looking but warm!)

Comment: It is 宁愿...也不... not 宁愿...也...

Comment: Correct, I slipped up there, must be the cold!

Comment: 其实, 是不是这样的: "宁愿A也不愿B" 愿 = 希望？？

Comment: 愿 means 愿意, or 想要,  to wish, to want, willing (to do sth), like the lyrics in the song 童话 **fairy tale**: **我愿变成**童话里你要的那个天使 means **I wish to be** the angel you need in fairy tale.