# Does expression ”宁愿...也不...“ belong only to book style or I can use it in simple conversation？

Tags: usage

I just met in book such sort of expressions with ”宁愿...也不...“. I understand it like "rather...than...", but my question is: is it only book style or spoken as well, **can I use such form in simple conversation?**
Thank you!

Comment: Related: [How does 也 work in 宁愿冻死也不穿?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/28015/how-does-也-work-in-宁愿冻死也不穿)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I use such form in simple conversation?

Yes. It's a common structure used in both written and spoken, formal and casual,  context. E.g. 我宁愿把它扔掉也不给你。

Answer (score 2):

When the context calls for it, use it in conversation, according to a quick survey of 2 friends!

我宁愿坐火车去。
I'd prefer to go by train.
我宁愿买二手货。
I prefer to buy second hand.
我宁愿跟铅管约会。
I'd rather date a lead pipe.

Comment: That is good reminding that 宁愿 _can be used by itself_. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"宁愿...也不..." is actually more colloquial than "宁...不..."

> "宁愿被殺也不投降" (colloquial)
>
> "宁死不降" (literary)

~

> "宁愿投降给美国，也不投降给苏朕" (colloquial)
>
> "宁降美不降苏" (literary)

~

> 宁愿冤枉好人，也不放走罪人(colloquial)
>
> 宁枉毋縱 (literary)

As you can see, literary phrases are much shorter, using them is speech have a lot of benefit.

In any case, both colloquial and literary phrases are commonly used in day to day speech and written text.

Comment: I've got it! Literary phrases are shorter, just like 单音词的文言文？很有趣！